# Some audio files play, but others do not

Tags: vb.net, audio, wav

I have a VB project which I am making. I have added `.wav` files to the resources so that I can play them. However, some files play, and some do not. `platform` doesn't play, however `formedOf` does. The `.wavs` play fine with Media Player, so they are not corrupted.

### Code

```
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.platform, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.formedOf, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
```

### Resources

[image: Image of My Resources]

Comment: Are they all .wav files?

Comment: @DavidWilson Yes, they are.

Comment: And I presume that if you double click on the file in windows explorer it plays ok? If thats the case then I really have no idea i'm afraid. If it doesn't play using explorer, maybe the file is corrupt?

Comment: @DavidWilson Yes, it does. I will try to copy the project into a new folder, and try from there, but it's really strange that this is happening.

Comment: @DavidWilson To further my last comment, I have tried to copy and run the project from a new folder after deleting all the resources and re-adding them, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yup - I dont know - Do you have the code to play the file in a try..catch block? It might be that if the catch block is empty, you wont see any exceptions that are getting thrown. Try commenting out the try, the catch and any code in the block

Comment: @DavidWilson No, my code isn't in a `Try`...`Catch` block... I'm converting all my audio into stereo from mono to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try re-recording the [wav](/questions/tagged/wav) files. If you recorded in mono, try in stereo, or vice versa. If none of these work, try recreating the project completely, ensuring you **DO NOT** copy/paste anything over.

Hope this helps!